# Insert shadow to active link

Tags: css

I have menu this html tabs:

```
<div class="myTabs">

  <a href="#empleados" aria-controls="empleados" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Employee</a>
  <a href="#puestos" class="active" aria-controls="puestos" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Global</a>
  <div style="clear:both;"></div>
</div>
```

Css:

```
 .myTabs {
   border: 1px solid #797979;
   background: #ffffff;
   background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0%, #d6d6d6 100%);
   background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0%, #d6d6d6 100%);
   background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #ffffff 0%, #d6d6d6 100%);
   filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#d6d6d6', GradientType=0);
 }

 .myTabs a {
   color: #000000;
   border-left: 1px solid #797979;
   display: block;
   padding: 5px 10px;
   float: right;
   text-decoration: none;
 }

 .myTabs a:hover {
   background: #ffffff;
   background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #d6d6d6 0%, #ffffff 100%);
   background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #d6d6d6 0%, #ffffff 100%);
   background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #d6d6d6 0%, #ffffff 100%);
   filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#d6d6d6', endColorstr='#ffffff', GradientType=0);
   text-decoration: none;
 }

 .myTabs a:active,
 .myTabs a:visited {
   text-decoration: none;
 }
```

That I want to do is to insert shadow to selected  link. For example If I pick Employee table, keep it selected with shadow and if I select Global one dissapear selected from Employee and select Global. How can I achive it?

There is a demo: [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qh33s2d6/4/)

```css
 .myTabs {
   border: 1px solid #797979;
   background: #ffffff;
   background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0%, #d6d6d6 100%);
   background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0%, #d6d6d6 100%);
   background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #ffffff 0%, #d6d6d6 100%);
   filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#d6d6d6', GradientType=0);
 }
 
 .myTabs a {
   color: #000000;
   border-left: 1px solid #797979;
   display: block;
   padding: 5px 10px;
   float: right;
   text-decoration: none;
 }
 
 .myTabs a:hover {
   background: #ffffff;
   background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #d6d6d6 0%, #ffffff 100%);
   background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #d6d6d6 0%, #ffffff 100%);
   background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #d6d6d6 0%, #ffffff 100%);
   filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#d6d6d6', endColorstr='#ffffff', GradientType=0);
   text-decoration: none;
 }
 
 .myTabs a:active,
 .myTabs a:visited {
   text-decoration: none;
 }
```

```html
<div class="myTabs">

  <a href="#empleados" aria-controls="empleados" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Employee</a>
  <a href="#puestos" class="active" aria-controls="puestos" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Global</a>
  <div style="clear:both;"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: You might need js for this. Are you ok with it?

Comment: Yes, I can use js without problems @GerardoBLANCO

Comment: Whats the active class for?

Comment: it don´t do anything, I just added for test @GerardoBLANCO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this is what you are looking for. I could do a jQuery solution that will work a lot easier.

I had to add class `tabs` to each tab so we can select it easier. And added the `.active` style to make the tabs shados

```js
(function() {
  var tabs = document.getElementsByClassName('tab');

  for (i = 0; i < tabs.length; i++) {

    tabs[i].addEventListener('click', function(e) {
      removeActive();
      e.target.classList.add('active');
    })
  }
})();


function removeActive() {
var tabs = document.getElementsByClassName('tab');
  for (i = 0; i < tabs.length; i++) {
    tabs[i].classList.remove('active')
  }
}
```

```css
.myTabs {
  border: 1px solid #797979;
  background: #ffffff;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0%, #d6d6d6 100%);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0%, #d6d6d6 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #ffffff 0%, #d6d6d6 100%);
  filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#d6d6d6', GradientType=0);
}

.myTabs a {
  color: #000000;
  border-left: 1px solid #797979;
  display: block;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  float: right;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.myTabs a:hover {
  background: #ffffff;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #d6d6d6 0%, #ffffff 100%);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #d6d6d6 0%, #ffffff 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #d6d6d6 0%, #ffffff 100%);
  filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#d6d6d6', endColorstr='#ffffff', GradientType=0);
  text-decoration: none;
}

.myTabs a:active,
.myTabs a:visited {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.active {
  box-shadow: 0px 5px 5px grey;
}
```

```html
<div id='myTabs' class="myTabs">

  <a href="#empleados" class="tab" aria-controls="empleados" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Employee</a>
  <a href="#puestos" class="active tab" aria-controls="puestos" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Global</a>
  <div style="clear:both;"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could certainly use JavaScript object-oriented!  I assigned an `id` attribute to each button, created a JavaScript class called `Tab`, and updated your `.myTabs a:hover` CSS so that it is also applied to any element with a CSS class of `selected`.  Does this work for your needs?

```js
var tabs = [];

class Tab
{
  select()
  {
    $("#" + this.id).addClass("selected");
  }

  deselect()
  {
    $("#" + this.id).removeClass("selected");
  }

  handle_click()
  {
    // deselect all other tabs
    for (var i = 0; i < tabs.length; ++i)
      tabs[i].deselect();
    
    // select this tab
    this.select();
  }

  constructor(id)
  {
    var tab = this;
  
    this.id = id;     // record HTML id for future use
    tabs.push(this);  // save tab in global list of all tabs
    
    // add listener for click event
    $("#" + this.id).click(function(){
      tab.handle_click();
    });
  }
}


$(function() {
  new Tab("empleados");
  new Tab("puestos");
});
```

```css
 .myTabs {
   border: 1px solid #797979;
   background: #ffffff;
   background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0%, #d6d6d6 100%);
   background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0%, #d6d6d6 100%);
   background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #ffffff 0%, #d6d6d6 100%);
   filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#d6d6d6', GradientType=0);
 }
 
 .myTabs a {
   color: #000000;
   border-left: 1px solid #797979;
   display: block;
   padding: 5px 10px;
   float: right;
   text-decoration: none;
 }
 
 .myTabs a:hover, .myTabs a.selected {
   background: #ffffff;
   background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #d6d6d6 0%, #ffffff 100%);
   background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #d6d6d6 0%, #ffffff 100%);
   background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #d6d6d6 0%, #ffffff 100%);
   filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#d6d6d6', endColorstr='#ffffff', GradientType=0);
   text-decoration: none;
 }
 
 .myTabs a:active,
 .myTabs a:visited {
   text-decoration: none;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="myTabs">

  <a id="empleados" href="#empleados" aria-controls="empleados" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Employee</a>
  <a id="puestos" href="#puestos" class="active" aria-controls="puestos" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Global</a>
  <div style="clear:both;"></div>
</div>
```